# Algebra linearly isomorphic to a tensor product is a free module

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I have an algebra $\mathcal P$ that is isomorphic as a vector space to $\mathcal H \otimes \mathcal J$ for $\mathcal H\subset \mathcal P$ and $\mathcal J\subset \mathcal P$. 
It follows that $\mathcal P $ is a free $\mathcal J$-module with $\dim \mathcal H$ generators.

Why does this follow?

Comment: I presume the tensor product is over the linear space's definition field...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $\mathcal{H}=k^n$ for your field over which $\mathcal{H}$ is a vector field. Now $\mathcal{H}$ has the form $\mathcal{H}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n k$ and since tensor product commutes with direct sum you get

$$ \left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n k\right)\otimes_{k} \mathcal{J}=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \left( k\otimes_k \mathcal{J} \right).$$

Now using that $k\otimes_k \mathcal{J}=\mathcal{J}$ you get $\mathcal{P}\simeq  \mathcal{J}^n$.